# When plotting values over a large period of time, the dates populate out of order

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot many years of data to view the trends that my data takes. When utilizing plot(dx) I get a date vs. value plot, but the date jumps around and doesn't seem to be in order. Below is the code I am utilizing, and a copy of the plot that is produced. Any help would be appreciated.

```
oz8<-(SRDAILYAVG_1004$Ozone.8.hr.Max.Value)
dd<-(SRDAILYAVG_1004$Date)
MDA8<-exp(oz8)
dx<-data.frame(date=dd,value=MDA8)
plot(dx)
```

A sample of the data stored in dx is provided as well.

```
241  8/29/2001      NaN
242  8/30/2001      NaN
243  8/31/2001 1.019182
244   9/1/2001 1.031486
245   9/2/2001 1.030455
246   9/3/2001 1.025315
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your date variable is actually a date object? There's a chance it is character.

Comment: ...maybe try `dd <- as.Date(SRDAILYAVG_1004$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")` and plot again.

Comment: Converting it to a date object worked. Thank you so much